# Conditional styling import gets bundle together after build in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm got stuck in this,

```
if (condition) {
  import("./style1.css");
} else {
  import("./style2.css");
}
```

When trying to import styling conditionally. It works locally, But when you build the app then both styles combines. And gets conflicts.

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using below in your babel configuration.

```
@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import
```

you need to configure Babel to transpile your dynamic imports.

Also the Webpack syntax mentions to use it like a promise.

Comment: Thanks Once Again.
No I'm not using @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import.
Also I've tried import using promise still not working.
Could you explain updation in babel configuration.

Comment: Ok, you would need to use this plugin - so that dynamic import works , Here is an article to provide some assistance https://blog.jscrambler.com/how-to-make-your-app-faster-with-webpack-dynamic-imports/ . If you don't use babel at all then require.ensure is another way. Give the above two a try and let know.